# Get data with Axios whose name contains parentheses

Tags: reactjs, axios, fetch, use-effect, use-state

I am currently experiencing a problem with my axios request.

Here is an example of the result of my query:

```
{
"results": [
{
"first_result": "123",
"second_result(abc)": "456"
}
]
}
```

As you can see, the second line contains parentheses.
How can I get this data (here "456"), with my useState?

```
 axios
      .get(API)
      .then((response) => response.data)
      .then((data) => {
       setObject(data.results[0].second_result(abc)))
        
        
      })
```

Thank you very much and have an nice day ! =)

Comment: did the answers help you ?

Answer (score 0):

Like this:

`data.results[0]['second_result(abc)']`

Answer (score 0):

You will need to access `second_result(abc)` using bracket notation because property name is not an valid javascript identifier. like `a.results[0]['second_result(abc)']`